# C# (Unity) -- Data not getting to scripts

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Just some background: I am trying to make a mini quiz game (very simple, not commercial or anything) in unity. I was following unity's tutorial on how to do this, but I am running into this error and I am not sure how to debug it. I can tell from looking online this is a common error but I can't see what I am doing wrong.

I am getting a NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object error in the HandleClick() function in my AnswerButton script and I am not sure how answerData is empty. I also have DataController, QuestionData, and RoundData scripts.

[image showing data filled in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqHKw.png)

This is my AnswerButton script:

```
public class AnswerButton : MonoBehaviour {

private AnswerData answerData;
private GameController gameController;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    gameController = FindObjectOfType<GameController>();
}

public void Setup(AnswerData data)
{
    answerData = data;
}

public void HandleClick()
{
    gameController.AnswerButtonClicked(answerData.isCorrect);
}
}
```

This is my AnswerData script:

```
 [System.Serializable]
 public class AnswerData {
     public string answerText;
     public bool isCorrect;
 }
```

GameController script:

```
public class GameController : MonoBehaviour {

[SerializeField] private Text questionText;
[SerializeField] private Text scoreText;

private DataController dataController;
private RoundData currentRoundData;
private QuestionData[] questionPool;
private AnswerData answerData;
private AnswerButton answerButton;

public GameObject questionDisplay;
public GameObject roundEndDisplay;

private bool isRoundActive;
private float timeRemaining;
private int questionIndex;
private int playerScore;

private void Start()
{
    dataController = FindObjectOfType<DataController>();
    currentRoundData = dataController.GetCurrentRoundData();
    questionPool = currentRoundData.questions;
    timeRemaining = currentRoundData.timeLimitInSeconds;

    playerScore = 0;
    questionIndex = 0;

    ShowQuestion();
    isRoundActive = true;

}

private void ShowQuestion()
{
    QuestionData questionData = questionPool[questionIndex];
    questionText.text = questionData.questionText;
    answerButton.Setup(answerData);

}

public void AnswerButtonClicked(bool isCorrect)
{
    if (isCorrect)
    {
        playerScore += currentRoundData.pointsAddedForCorrectAnswer;
        scoreText.text = "Score: " + playerScore.ToString();
    }

    if (questionPool.Length > questionIndex + 1)
    {
        questionIndex++;
        ShowQuestion();
    } else
    {
        EndRound();
    }
}

public void EndRound()
{
    isRoundActive = false;

    questionDisplay.SetActive(false);
    roundEndDisplay.SetActive(true);
}
}
```

Comment: where are you callin your setup method? without that answerdata is null.

Comment: Im calling it in the GameController, but I am getting the same error on that line of code. Which is: answerButton.Setup(answerData);

Comment: thats the root of your error, its just getting passed to this and causing another one.. lol

Comment: show me your whole Gamecontroller please i want to see how you are filling answer data, i mean i see your filling it out in the inspector, but i want to see how its set up maybe i can help

Comment: I added the game controller. I'm sorry if this is really dumb

Comment: Your answerButton is private but not serialized. I'm thinking you haven't set any value to it so you are getting null reference on that.

Comment: If AnswerButton is a MonoBehaviour/GameObject, get it at the `Start()` function the same way you get DataController. If it is not a MonoBehaviour, create its instance `answerButton = new AnswerButton()`

Comment: I added this line of code: `answerButton = FindObjectOfType<AnswerButton>();` to the start  method, and that moved the error to this: `gameController.AnswerButtonClicked(answerData.isCorrect);` line of code in the AnswerButton script

Comment: Software engineering is not a guessing game. You need to know exactly what happens. Just add logging to HandleClick method and see if gameController or answerData is null (or both :D). Used Debug.Log for that: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.Log.html

Comment: well i know its null but i dont know why haha. I don't know how its becoming null

Comment: Can you check which one is null? Add `Debug.Log(gameController == null ? "Game Controller is Null" : "Game Controller is Working");` and `Debug.Log(answerData == null ? "Answer Data is Null" : "Answer Data is Working");`. And just as @SergeyKrusch said, you shouldn't guess what is not getting null values.

Comment: Sorry I believe I was misunderstanding what he was asking. I added those two lines and Answer Data is null, game controller is working

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably in your `GameController` class. The `answerData` variable is never set (since it is private, it can only be set in your GameController class, and it isn't), but it is being used in `ShowQuestion()`.

You probably have to add some code in `ShowQuestion()` or some other method in `GameController` to retrieve the answers from your `DataController` object and put it into `answerData`. Right now, nothing is doing that, so `answerData` is null and Unity returns the error.